# How to implement AWS Cognito (ionic)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement AWS cognito service into my app (ionic 2/3), from scratch. I have no previous experience with AWS.

I did make work the ionic2-starter-aws project (even if the tutorial was missing a lot of things) but since I was importing a project into the mobile hub, I did not learn anything useful for my App.

What I did:

1. Made my app work without any AWS service.
2. Created a mobile hub, added a user pool (User Sign-in)
3. Activated Hosting And Streaming (from the Mobile Hub) and downloaded aws-config.js
4. Copy/pasted providers files from https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-aws /src/providers/  (they were made for aws connection, no point in re-writing them I guess)

Here I tried adding aws-config.js different way (into src/assets, same place than index.html, at the project root, ...) without success, all I get is `AWSCognito is not defined`. This error laid almost no result so I guess I forgot/did something wrong at some point (I am guessing it come from `declare var AWSCognito: any;` inside aws.cognito.ts but it wasn't declared before, but why does it work with ionic2-starter-aws then ?)

What are the steps to implement Cognito ? Lots have been made for javascript but they doesn't seem to work for typescript ?